# Java library for data visualization

Tags: java, visualization

I'm looking for a library for data visualization that's make it possible to visualize components and their relationship as done [here](http://tools.niem.gov/niemtools/viewer/DataModelViewer.iepd).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you mean charting libraries ?

Comment: I *know* you said Java, but all the cool kids are using [D3.js](http://d3js.org) these days. Java in the browser is dying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JFreeChart is a free 100% Java chart library that makes it easy for developers to display professional quality charts in their applications. Check more on the official website:

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Other options are

https://code.google.com/p/charts4j/

https://developers.google.com/chart/